# boomerangJS for SPA with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, boomerang

I am trying to use boomerangJS for SPA built using AngularJS

`using plugins: plugins/rt.js plugins/navtiming.js plugins/auto_xhr.js plugins/spa.js plugins/angular.js`

with init

```
BOOMR.init({
    beacon_url: 'http://myValidDomaincom/test.gif',
    autorun: false,
    instrument_xhr: false
  });
```

Angular plugin is hooked using below code:

```
.run(['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
var hadRouteChange = false;
$rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function() {
    hadRouteChange = true;
});

function hookAngularBoomerang() {
    if (window.BOOMR && BOOMR.version) {
        if (BOOMR.plugins && BOOMR.plugins.Angular) {
            BOOMR.plugins.Angular.hook($rootScope, hadRouteChange);
        }
        return true;
    }
}

if (!hookAngularBoomerang()) {
    if (document.addEventListener) {
        document.addEventListener("onBoomerangLoaded", hookAngularBoomerang);
    } else if (document.attachEvent) {
        document.attachEvent("onpropertychange", function(e) {
            e = e || window.event;
            if (e && e.propertyName === "onBoomerangLoaded") {
                hookAngularBoomerang();
            }
        });
    }
}
}])
```

And when first time page is loaded I trigger `BOOMR.page_ready();` using JS

Now when I go through the flow which loads different views, I don't see any new beacons getting triggered

- What's the expected behavior?
- Will boomerang trigger new beacons each time a new view is displayed on page ?
- Am I missing any configuration or code, to get it working ?

Comment: You should ask this question on the boomerang issues list here: https://github.com/lognormal/boomerang/issues  The dev team actively responds to questions, and someone else may have run into this issue already.

Comment: thx @bluesmoon added @github.com/lognormal/boomerang/issues

Comment: @bluesmoon can you plz check for https://github.com/SOASTA/boomerang/issues/85

Comment: looks like this was handled.

Comment: @lucky  I am also trying to implement SPA in my angular 7 application. So I have added this code in index.html under script tag. However I am getting .run is undefined. I tried BOOMR.run as well but it's saying run is not a function. Can you please help me to implement in Angular7. Thanks

Comment: @bluesmoon  I am also trying to implement SPA in my angular 7 application. So I have added this code in index.html under script tag. However I am getting .run is undefined. I tried BOOMR.run as well but it's saying run is not a function. Can you please help me to implement in Angular7. Can you please share any demo application if you have created. Thanks

Comment: @vikas, please ask on the boomerang GitHub page. Stackoverflow is not the boomerang support site.